# Testing with Minitest validation of translation presence using mobility gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, mobility

Testing an application that implements the mobility gem with Minitest, a custom validator

```
class CustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if translation_exists?(record, attribute)
      record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || :taken)
    end
  end

  private

  def translation_exists?(record, attribute)
    attribute, locale = attribute.to_s.split('_')
    record.class.joins(:string_translations).exists?(
      mobility_string_translations: { locale: locale, key: attribute }
    )
  end
end
```

is invoked in the model as follows:

```
  validates :name, presence: true
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    validates :"name_#{locale}", presence: true, custom: true
  end
```

the model has a focus locale (that which is being learned) and is destined to populate  the `name` column and be present.
An array of translations also needs to be present (for now all available_locales).

But the following test fails:

```
  test "validity of fixtures" do
    assert tags(:en_assigned).valid?
  end
```

because the fixture

```
en_assigned:
  name: MyString
```

is deemed invalid as a `puts tags(:en_assigned).errors.first.full_message` is adamant that
`Name can't be blank`  which is unexpected?

How can this setup be effectively tested?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be incomplete, but does address the issue.
The error arises in the database migration relative to the goal at hand.

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :element, index: true, null: false
  [...]
```

the `, null: false` is what gums up the works; the presence of mobility will populate the translation table, but not the class column.  If one really desires to hold the original value and ensure it is not empty, it should be a separate column - unlss proven otherwise, at present, the saving of a master value in the column is not a funciotn carried out by the `mobility` gem.

Then it becomes possible to define which locale(s) need to be validated by adjusting the above to something like:

```
  [:de, :es].each do |locale|
    validates :"name_#{locale}", presence: true, custom: true
  end
```